# When it's about pages of a book, should I use until, through or up to?

Tags: prepositions

If I finished reading part of a book, should I use:

> 1. I read the book until page 20.
> 2. I read the book up to page 20.
> 3. I read the book through page 20.

Answer (score 1):

1. ***Until** page 20* is not idiomatic, and I would not use it.
2. ***Up to** page 20* is ambiguous. I would usually interpret it as meaning "to and including page 20" but strictly speaking it means "to but *not* including page 20" (i.e. you have read page 19 and no further). You should avoid using this, or include the clarifier "and including" or "but not including" as appropriate.
3. ***Through** page 20* means all pages including page 20. It is unambiguous.